# How can I make an ICU data file with information for emojis only

Tags: c, icu

I'm trying to pare down the `libicudata.a` file to the bare minimum that would still allow me to be able to test the following:

```
u_stringHasBinaryProperty(icu::UnicodeString::fromUTF8("").getBuffer(), -1, UProperty::UCHAR_RGI_EMOJI);
```

As per the instructions found [here](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu_data/buildtool.html), I crafted the following file file and used it accordingly when configuring ICU's build.

```
{
  "strategy": "additive",
  "resourceFilters": [
    {
      "categories": [
        "misc"
      ],
      "files": {
        "includelist": [
          "emoji-sequences",
          "emoji-zwj-sequences"
        ]
      },
      "rules": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I did end up with a (much) smaller file (17kb) but it's obviously not working. M code compiles, links and runs but fails the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good folks at icu-support@lists.sourceforge.net helped me out. The information was (temporarily) missing from their documentation. The following filter is what I was looking for:

```
{
  "strategy": "additive",
  "featureFilters": {
    "uemoji": "include"
  }
}
```